# Missing nodes in multidimensional array tree

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

Trying to create tree in multidimensional array  with the following code

```
$source = array(
(array('id'=>406,'parent'=>0,'title'=>'level_0_406')),
(array('id'=>270,'parent'=>268,'title'=>'level_0_406_268_270')),
(array('id'=>271,'parent'=>268,'title'=>'level_0_406_268_271')),
(array('id'=>272,'parent'=>268,'title'=>'level_0_406_268_272')),
(array('id'=>273,'parent'=>268,'title'=>'level_0_406_268_273)')),
(array('id'=>269,'parent'=>268,'title'=>'level_0_406_268_269')),
(array('id'=>268,'parent'=>406,'title'=>'level_0_406_268')),
(array('id'=>407,'parent'=>406,'title'=>'level_0_406_407')),
(array('id'=>274,'parent'=>406,'title'=>'level_0_406_274')),
(array('id'=>500,'parent'=>407,'title'=>'level_0_406_407_500')),
);

$result = array();
$links = array(0=>&$result);

foreach ($source as &$element){
    $links[$element['id']] = &$element;     
    $links[$element['parent']]['childs'][$element['id']] = &$element;
}
```

But result array does not include several nodes of source array, viz. nodes with id=269,270,271,272,273.

```
Array
(
    [childs] => Array
        (
            [406] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 406
                    [parent] => 0
                    [title] => level_0_406
                    [childs] => Array
                        (
                            [268] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 268
                                    [parent] => 406
                                    [title] => level_0_406_268
                                )

                            [407] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 407
                                    [parent] => 406
                                    [title] => level_0_406_407
                                    [childs] => Array
                                        (
                                            [500] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [id] => 500
                                                    [parent] => 407
                                                    [title] => level_0_406_407_500
                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                            [274] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 274
                                    [parent] => 406
                                    [title] => level_0_406_274
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

I tried different code examples of tree generation but all of them have the same issue with source array like $source. Please help me understand such behavior.

**Update** 
Now i understand what is wrong with array. But what if i have such data in DB, how to make selection properly? $source array should be specially sorted before using tree generation function.

Comment: Several issues with your code there :-?. 1) You have $links['id'] and $links['parent'] but are using $links['cat_id'] and $links['parent_id']. 2) You are using the reference operator (&) kinda often and I'm uncertain if your app logic specifically requires that. 3) $links[$element['cat_id']] and $links[$element['parent_id']] might clash and over-write eachother :-?

Comment: 1.arrays names fixed 2.it's not my own code, just used one of solutions

Answer (score 1):

The original `$source` array values are not properly created. It should be:-

```
$source = array(
  (array('id'=>406,'parent'=>0,'title'=>'level_0_406')),
  (array('id'=>268,'parent'=>406,'title'=>'level_0_406_268')),
  (array('id'=>407,'parent'=>406,'title'=>'level_0_406_407')),
  (array('id'=>274,'parent'=>406,'title'=>'level_0_406_274')),
  (array('id'=>270,'parent'=>268,'title'=>'level_0_406_268_270')),
  (array('id'=>271,'parent'=>268,'title'=>'level_0_406_268_271')),
  (array('id'=>272,'parent'=>268,'title'=>'level_0_406_268_272')),
  (array('id'=>273,'parent'=>268,'title'=>'level_0_406_268_273)')),
  (array('id'=>269,'parent'=>268,'title'=>'level_0_406_268_269')),
  (array('id'=>500,'parent'=>407,'title'=>'level_0_406_407_500')),
);
```

If you look carefully, you will see that previously, only the child element of the parent element ID `407` was available, since the element ID `407` has been defined before the occurrence of the child element.

It is the de-facto of your coding logic to have the parent elements defined first followed by the definitions of the child elements. Also the general practice & standard has always been the same.

In my answer, I have changed the occurrence of the elements properly. This should work.

Hope it helps.

Comment: (sidenote) These 5 missing nodes was parentless children (for parent 268) :) +1

Comment: @Wh1T3h4Ck5 - Yep, well said, according to the construction of `$source` in the question, those 5 nodes are surely parentless. Now those children nodes have a parent, and they are no more orphans. ;)

Comment: it really helps. that you for fast answer. but it looks like that now i have a little bit more difficult issue, because $source array i get from database (ORDER BY parent), and i have no idea how to sort it right way to create tree properly.